# How to show json data in a admin grid

Tags: admin, grid

Can I show json data I pull from some api in admin grid? Currently I tried to create varien data collection. But its not working. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Poll_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = new Varien_Db_Collection();
        if ( Mage::registry('json_data') )
        {   
            $data=json_decode(Mage::registry('json_data'));         
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
                $rowObj->setData($row);
                $collection->addItem($rowObj);
            }           
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id', array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'index'=>'id',
            'header'=>$this->__('Print Id')
        ));
        $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'index'=>'customer_email',
            'header'=>$this->__('Customer Email')
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

> Change collection class Varien_Db_Collection to Varien_Data_Collection

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection(); 
    if ( Mage::registry('json_data') )
    {   
        $data=json_decode(Mage::registry('json_data'));         
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
            $rowObj->setData($row);
            $collection->addItem($rowObj);
        }           
    }
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: @Dushan you can upvote as well

Comment: I need this but on M2 :( Don't know if I have to create Varien_Data_Collection too? and how?